# What are the difference between Bloc provider and Normal Provider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, bloc

```
Which is more easy and effective for flutter?
```

1. Two use this two providers have any platform performance related issue.
2. App fastness possibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

they are 2 different approaches and it's not that one is better than the other BlocProvider injects a bloc where you emit events and get responses,

Provider is easier to use and to get started but performance wise you will be ok with both approaches as long as you follow the correct principles